# Should I apply counting in DB or in Code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have the following code where I'm trying to get the amount of rows in the same `dataset` with various matches.

My question is if should I get the count in C# code with a `IEnumerable` or by querying a `IQueryable` from database?

Which one is more efficient, multiple database transactions or `IEnumerable` filtering and count?

```
public List<Tuple<string, int>> CalismaVeIzinleriHesapla(long personelId, DateTime baslangic, DateTime bitis)
{
    var hesaplamalar = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
    var puantajList = puantajlar.Where(p => p.PersonelId == personelId && (p.Tarih >= baslangic && p.Tarih <= bitis));

    var haftaTatili = puantajList.Where(p => p.Secenek.Deger == "Ht").Count();
    var resmiTatil = puantajList.Where(p => p.Secenek.Deger == "Rt").Count();
    var yillikIzin = puantajList.Where(p => p.Secenek.Deger == "Yi").Count();
    var odenecekRapor = puantajList.Where(p => p.Secenek.Deger == "R+").Count();
    var dogumIzni = puantajList.Where(p => p.Secenek.Deger == "Di").Count();
    var olumIzni = puantajList.Where(p => p.Secenek.Deger == "Öi").Count();
    var evlilikIzni = puantajList.Where(p => p.Secenek.Deger == "Ei").Count();
    var odenmeyecekRapor = puantajList.Where(p => p.Secenek.Deger == "R-").Count();
    var ucretsizIzin = puantajList.Where(p => p.Secenek.Deger == "Üi").Count();
    var devamsizlik = puantajList.Where(p => p.Secenek.Deger == "D").Count(); 

    return hesaplamalar;
}
```

Comment: In truth, you don't *technically* need to worry about it. If you're counting an `IQueryable<T>`, it will intelligently either go to the database if the result is not present, or count in memory if it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for your case, querying and counting in the db is more efficient.
something like this would be efficient.

```
puantajlar
  .Where(p => p.PersonelId == personelId && (p.Tarih >= baslangic && p.Tarih <= bitis))
  .GroupBy(x => x.Secenek.Deger)
  .Select(group => new { group.Key, Count = group.Count()  })
```

Comment: In what kind of scenario counting from memory would be more efficient ? If I couldn't handle it in one transaction would it be better to count them in memory ? What is the fine line between SQL complexity and performance ? I know it's a lot but I'm always confused by these decisions  :)

Comment: 1) Always go for db unless you can't
2) If you already retrieved the records (for other reasons) counting them in memory is totally acceptable

Comment: @amd my situation is more like the second one which I already fetched the dataset in previous methods so I can utilize the same one for these functions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> My question is if should I get the count in C# code with a IEnumarable or by querying a IQueryable in DB

If you need only the count of the rows then count must be done in database, not in memory. If you do count in memory by pulling the data list from database into memory then it will waste your server memory unnecessarily and cost performance.

Comment: I'm not mainly concerned about the memory cause the data is not huge. So you say even though each count is one extra transaction from database counting in memory would be slower ?

Comment: @brainoverflow98 Event if you do it in memory then  to pull data you have to make transaction to database every time. Isn't it?. So I always prefer counting on database rather than pulling in memory unnecessarily whether the data set is large or not.

Comment: I think I could do it all in onc transactions to fetch the data I need to memory. Anyways the answer @amd provided looks quite nice. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Complexity and Performance, both of them depends on your situation, if there are no huge data the `Performance` is no matter, but sometime you have to make a decision based on your situation. 
By running your code it should connect to DB and run the `count` query in each line of code 
it is 100 per cent clear that counting same rows in DB is more efficient in one shoot so you can do something like :

```
select p.Secenek.Deger,
....
sum(case when p.Secenek.Deger = 'Ht' then 1 else 0 end) haftaTatili,
sum(case when p.Secenek.Deger = 'Rt' then 1 else 0 end) resmiTatil
.....
from puantajlar p
group by p.Secenek.Deger
```

or you can do it in more efficient way by grouping them in one shoot also like @amd mentioned:

```
puantajlar
  .Where(p => p.PersonelId == personelId && (p.Tarih >= baslangic && p.Tarih <= bitis))
  .GroupBy(x => x.Secenek.Deger)
  .Select(group => new { group.Key, Count = group.Count()  })
```

Comment: So you say in either way I shouldn't go with applying operations to dataset in memory  ?

Comment: Applying the query with `dataset` or something else like `EF` is not important as how your code should run, finally you have to use an ORM to access the count fields either `dataset` or something, but this is important how query should be run, one by one or all them in one query.